# Why every time I close Google Chrome v.35.0 is killing windows 7? Blue screen attached

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Can someone give me a hand please? I have been ignoring this issue for the least 6 months but now I'm tire of it. The only solution I have is to reinstall windows, but setting up my "developer" configuration is 3 days pain minimum. Do you know why every time I close Google Chrome v.35.0 is killing windows 7? Blue screen attached

[image]

[image]

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Try running BlueScreenView on your machine, from Nirsoft. It pretty much automates what we'd tell you to do. It's free.

Comment: What did you try so far? For example, do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)? Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome? Does the system work fine if you don't use Chrome at all? You might consider attaching the output provided by BlueScreenView at the very least, but without analyzing the actual `.dmp` files (usually stored in `C:\Windows\Minidump`) it's harder to troubleshoot such issues.

Comment: @MarkAllen thanks for your time. I installed BlueScreenView as you suggested and I just update the post and upload the image. I hope that can help for something.

Comment: @and31415 thanks for your time. I installed BlueScreenView as you suggested and I just update the post and upload the image. I hope that can help for something.

Comment: Now in BlueScreenView click File, Google Search Bugcheck + Parameter 1 and see if that brings up anything. You can try the Bugcheck + Driver as well.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a hardware issue, a few things I would try are:

- Reinstall Chrome
- Check your eventlog for error messages that would give any indication
- Check your hardware for any problems. A failing disk can cause driver corruptions. Faulty memory can cause bluescreens as well.
- Try a system restore from a point where everything was working happily (if you can afford to do this)
- Reinstall your hardware drivers (maybe a bad driver update came in with Windows update?)

Comment: Thanks mate! I installed BlueScreenView and I just update the post and upload the image. I hope that can help for something. do u think is something related to the driver or to Chrome?

Comment: It's really difficult to tell with the information you provided. You need to dig around a bit to extract relevant information from your system. If you can't figure it out, you should post any updates in your request.